# "Bad variable name" when trying to run phpunit tests via a Makefile without deprecation warnings

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, makefile, phpunit

I have a Make target called `test`. It looks like this:

```
test:
    /var/www//vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I want to set up a git hook that runs all tests before commits. In order to do this without getting stalled on deprecation warnings, I want to have my hook run a different Make target. It looks like this:

```
test-automated:
    export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER = disabled
    /var/www//vendor/bin/phpunit
```

However, when I try to run this target, I get this error message:

> export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER = "disabled" /bin/sh: export: line
> 1: : bad variable name make: *** [Makefile:14: test-automated] Error 2

**What can I do to make Make and PHPUnit run without deprecation warnings?**

Addendum: I also tried `export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled` and `export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER="disabled"`. In both of those cases, the Make target ran, but deprecation warnings were displayed, and Make exited with code 1, which is not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is the right way to do it.

A makefile recipe is a *shell script*, and the content of the recipe must be valid shell syntax; it can't be makefile syntax.  In the shell, variable assignment must not have whitespace around the equal sign; if you type this into your shell prompt:

```
$ export foo = bar
```

that is not assigning a variable `foo` to the value `bar` and exporting it; that is trying to export the 3 variables named `foo`, `=`, and `bar`, and `=` is not a valid shell variable name so you get this error.

Your change to make this `export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled` is right.

The reason it doesn't work is that each logical line in a recipe is run in a *separate* shell.  So assigning the variable on one logical line then running the program in another logical line is not going to work: the assignment on the first line is lost as soon as that shell exits.

You can use either one of:

```
test-automated:
        SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled /var/www//vendor/bin/phpunit
```

as you did or (less good IMO but will work):

```
test-automated:
        export SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled; \
          /var/www//vendor/bin/phpunit
```

by adding the `; \` at the end you've combined these two physical lines into one logical line.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a direct answer to the question I asked, but I found out that this works:

```
test-automated:
    SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=disabled /var/www//vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I'll leave the question open in case someone has a better answer.